# Loading a csv file in PyCharm generates error

Tags: python, pycharm, read.csv

I would like to understand what is wrong when importing the csv file from my project.
Here is the project structure:

[image]

I set the folder "TP1 - ...." as root directory but when I run
`pd.read_csv('iris.csv.')` from a python file in that directory, PyCharm returns a errore.

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'iris.csv'`

I looking within the Python Console and the path is available:

`sys.path.extend(['/Users/thomas/Documents/EFREI/Intro Machine Learning', '/Users/thomas/Documents/EFREI/Intro Machine Learning/TP1 - Exploration et visualisation de données avec Python', '/Users/thomas/Documents/EFREI/Intro Machine Learning/TP2 - Kmeans'])`

Does anyone know how to solve it and could explain to me what's happening?
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (where relative paths are resolved) of your program is wrong. Generally, PyCharm sets it to your project root unless otherwise instructed.

You can set it in the Run > Edit Configurations window, or you can just move `iris.csv` to the project root directory.

This has nothing to do with `sys.path` (which you should generally also *never* touch by hand, because it will lead to confusion more often than not). Considering your module names already have that `tp*` prefix, it might be better to just keep all of them in the project root, and move to a regular Python package structure later if you need to.

Comment: Thank you AKX. 

Can you explain a little bit more in details what you mean by "where relative paths are resolved" ?

I changed the working directory for my python file by setting to the parent folder (that contains both the python file and the csv file) but it doesnt work

Comment: Please see the Wikipedia article about what the working directory means. Also try `print(os.getcwd())` in your script to see the actual value.